# Calling Azure SQL DW Stored Procedure from Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am getting the following error when trying to run a stored procedure in an Azure SQL Datawarehouse.

> Activity 'SprocActivitySample' contains an invalid Dataset reference 'Destination-SQLDW-nna'. This dataset is pointing to Azure SQL DW and stored procedure is in it.

Here is the entire code.

```
{
    "name": "SprocActivitySamplePipeline",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "type":"SqlServerStoredProcedure",
                "typeProperties": {
                    "storedProcedureName": "DailyImport",
                    "storedProcedureParameters": {
                        "DateToImportFor": "$$Text.Format('{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}', SliceStart)"
                    }
                },
                "outputs": [
                    {
                        "name": "Destination-SQLDW-nna"
                    }
                ],
                "scheduler": {
                    "frequency": "Day",
                    "interval": 1
                },
                "name": "SprocActivitySample"
            }
        ],
         "start": "2017-01-01T00:00:00Z",
         "end": "2017-02-20T05:00:00Z",
        "isPaused": true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that Azure Sql Data Warehouse does not support table-valued parameters in stored procedures.

Read more about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-develop-stored-procedures

If you find a workaround for it please share! I couldnt find any.

Also it would be good if you can post the dataset json so we can try to find any errors on it.

Cheers!

Comment: Hi, Azure SQL Data Warehouse does support parameters, but it does not support table-valued parameters.  Is that what you mean?  Please feel free to roll back my edit if it doesn't apply.

Comment: The documentation says it doesn't support: •table-valued parameters
•read-only parameters • default parameters. Is there any other kind of parameter? If so then your edit is alright.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working. the problem was that i was referencing wrong

```
                 "outputs": [
                    {
                        "name": "Destination-SQLDW-nna"
                    }
```

after correcting name to the right Dataset it is working